# How do you find the matrix M(T)?

Tags: linear-algebra

$T$ is defined by

$T(x,y,z)= (3x+2y+z,x+5z)$

Find the matrix $M(T,((1,0,0)(1,1,0),(1,1,1)),((1,0),(1,1)))$

So far I have gotten that $M(T)$ is $$ \begin{bmatrix}
        3 &2 &1  \\
        1 &0 & 5 \\
        \end{bmatrix} $$
But I do not know how to incorporate the other values

"$((1,0,0)(1,1,0),(1,1,1)),((1,0),(1,1))$"

Edit:Yes sorry for the lack of clarity, T is the transformation from $R^3$ to $R^2$ and I was asked to find $M(T,((1,0,0)(1,1,0),(1,1,1)),((1,0),(1,1)))$ .

Comment: I htink you have to use change of basis.

Comment: What does $M(T,\ldots)$ mean?

Comment: I think the question is asking you to write the matrix $M$ representing the given linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ with basis $B_1=\{(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with basis $B_2=\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$, do you know how to write a change of basis matrix?

Comment: If the ordered pairs are column vectors, then the answer is $\widehat {B_2} \cdot \left[\matrix{3&2&1\cr 1&0&5\cr}\right]\cdot \widehat{B_1}^{-1}$, where $\widehat A$ is the matrix you get by "gluing" the vectors in the basis together (to make a matrix).

Comment: What is a change of basis matrix?  Perhaps that is where I am struggling.

Comment: For example the vector $(2,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ in the basis $\{(3,1),(0,7)\}$ would be written as $(6,2)$ in the canonical base $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$. A change of basis matrix is a matrix representing the identity transformation going from $V$ with a basis to itself with another basis, basically it translates the coordinate of vectors written in a base into another one

Answer (score 1):

If we interpret $M(T,((1,0,0)(1,1,0),(1,1,1)),((1,0),(1,1)))$ as 'matrix representation of $T$  w.r.t. the bases $\{(1,0,0)^T,(1,1,0)^T,(1,1,1)^T\}$ (in the domain) and $\{(1,0)^T,(1,1)^T\}$ (in the codomain)' then translates to the task to:

1. Apply $T$ to the basis vector  $\{(1,0,0)^T,(1,1,0)^T,(1,1,1)^T\}$ in the domain, resulting in $v_1 = T((1,0,0)^T), v_2 = T((1,1,0)^T), v_3 = T((1,1,1)^T).$
2. Write these three vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ as linear combinations of $\{(1,0)^T,(1,1)^T\}$
3. Put the coordinates (i.e. the linear factors in front of $(1,0)^T,(1,1)^T$) of $v_1, v_2, v_3$ column-wise into a matrix.

Does this outlining of these steps help you?

Even though this look different, note that this is essentially the same as calculating $\hat B_2 A \hat B_1^{-1}$ from Carl Heckman's comment.